Subscriber Publisher Pattern using C# TPL DataFlow blocks
I'm trying to implement a Subscriber/Publisher or Producer/Consumers kind of a pattern using C# TPL DataFlow blocks. The idea is to let user subscribe to a Symbol for data and if he subscribes again the same symbol, instead of creating a new subscription return same subscription we already have. Once all subscriptions are closed, we gracefully dispose of all the resources.
My concern about my implementation is:

Am I using DataFlow blocks in a way they are supposed to be used?
Is it memory-leak free implementation?

BitFinexTickerSubscription is basically a single subscription that manages everything related to subscribing for data and managing subscribers.
BitfinexTickerExchange is like a subscription manager that manages all the different symbol subscriptions.
Need your suggestions in improving this implementation and understanding potential issues.
BitFinexTickerSubscription
internal class BitFinexTickerSubscription : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IBitfinexSocketClient _bitfinexSocketClient;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, ActionBlock<OpenTickerModel>> _subscribers = new();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new(1, 1);
    private BroadcastBlock<OpenTickerModel>? _subscription;
    private CancellationTokenSource? _cancellationTokenSource;
    private int _subscriptionId = -1;
    private bool _disposed;

    public string Symbol { get; private set; } = string.Empty;
    public int SubscribersCount => _subscribers.Count;

    public BitFinexTickerSubscription(IBitfinexSocketClient bitfinexSocketClient)
    {
        _bitfinexSocketClient =
            bitfinexSocketClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bitfinexSocketClient));
    }

    public async Task<bool> SubscribeAsync(string symbol)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            if (_subscription != null) return true;

            Symbol = symbol;
            var result = await _bitfinexSocketClient.SpotApi
                .SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync($"t{Symbol.ToUpper()}", OnUpdateReceived)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (result.Success)
            {
                _subscriptionId = result.Data.Id;
                _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                _subscription = new BroadcastBlock<OpenTickerModel>(null,
                    new DataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = _cancellationTokenSource.Token });
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    private void OnUpdateReceived(DataEvent<BitfinexStreamTicker> update)
    {
        var model = new OpenTickerModel
        {
            ExchangeSymbol = update.Symbol!,
            TickerSymbol = update.Symbol!.Replace("t", ""),
            BestAskPrice = update.Data.BestAskPrice,
            BestAskQuantity = update.Data.BestAskQuantity,
            BestBidPrice = update.Data.BestBidPrice,
            BestBidQuantity = update.Data.BestBidQuantity,
            LastPrice = update.Data.LastPrice,
            DailyChange = update.Data.DailyChange,
            DailyChangePercentage = update.Data.DailyChangePercentage,
            Volume = update.Data.Volume,
            HighPrice = update.Data.HighPrice,
            LowPrice = update.Data.LowPrice,
        };

        _subscription?.SendAsync(model);
    }

    public Guid AddSubscriber(Action<OpenTickerModel> action)
    {
        var key = Guid.NewGuid();
        var newSubscriber = new ActionBlock<OpenTickerModel>(action, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions());
        _subscribers[key] = newSubscriber;
        _subscription?.LinkTo(newSubscriber);

        return key;
    }

    public bool RemoveSubscriber(Guid key)
    {
        if (_subscribers.TryRemove(key, out var subscriber))
        {
            subscriber.Complete();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public async Task UnsubscribeAsync()
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            if (_subscriptionId > -1)
            {
                await _bitfinexSocketClient.SpotApi.UnsubscribeAsync(_subscriptionId).ConfigureAwait(false);
                _subscription?.Complete();

                foreach (var subscriber in _subscribers)
                {
                    RemoveSubscriber(subscriber.Key);
                }

                _subscribers.Clear();
                _subscriptionId = -1;

                if (_cancellationTokenSource != null)
                {
                    await _cancellationTokenSource.CancelAsync();
                    _cancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
                    _cancellationTokenSource = null;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            UnsubscribeAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            _semaphore.Dispose();
            _cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}

IBitfinexTickerExchange
public interface IBitfinexTickerExchange : IDisposable
{
    Task<Guid> SubscribeAsync(string symbol, Action<OpenTickerModel> action);
    Task<bool> UnsubscribeAsync(Guid key, string symbol);
}

BitfinexTickerExchange
public class BitfinexTickerExchange : IBitfinexTickerExchange
{
    private readonly IBitfinexSocketClient _bitfinexSocketClient;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, BitFinexTickerSubscription> _subscriptions = new();
    private bool _disposed;

    public BitfinexTickerExchange(IBitfinexSocketClient bitfinexSocketClient)
    {
        _bitfinexSocketClient =
            bitfinexSocketClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bitfinexSocketClient));
    }

    public async Task<Guid> SubscribeAsync(string symbol, Action<OpenTickerModel> action)
    {
        var subscription =
            _subscriptions.GetOrAdd(symbol, _ => new BitFinexTickerSubscription(_bitfinexSocketClient));
        await subscription.SubscribeAsync(symbol).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return subscription.AddSubscriber(action);
    }

    public async Task<bool> UnsubscribeAsync(Guid key, string symbol)
    {
        if (_subscriptions.TryGetValue(symbol, out var bitFinexTickerSubscription))
        {
            bitFinexTickerSubscription.RemoveSubscriber(key);
            if (bitFinexTickerSubscription.SubscribersCount <= 0)
            {
                await bitFinexTickerSubscription.UnsubscribeAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                _subscriptions.TryRemove(symbol, out _);
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed) return;

        if (disposing)
        {
            foreach (var subscription in _subscriptions.Values)
            {
                subscription.Dispose();
            }

            _subscriptions.Clear();
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}


Why OnUpdateReceived's return type is void not Task?

@PeterCsala yeah, it should be Task.

The SubscribeAsync method doesn't act like I would assume.  The first symbol passed in set a property and then a subscription is made based on that symbol.  If a different symbol is later passed in that is ignored by the if (_subscription != null) and the original symbol is still used and returns true.
I would change Addsubscriber to not return Guid but an IDisposbleAsync and allow the end user to dispose when done vs having to call UnsubscribeAsync.
From TPL data flow seems you just want to use broadcastblock and chain an action block to it. Have you considered using Rx.NET?
Depending on the call signature of SubscribeToTickerUpdatesAsync then OnUpdateRecieved should be Task instead of void.  If can't change the call signature then should signature another consumer to post async.
